# Having trouble with SQLite's INSERT INTO in C

Tags: c, database, sqlite

So, I'm trying to insert data into a table using SQLite in C. The insert works fine whenever I do it without specifying the columns I'm going to insert the data to. However, I want to use the primary key property in one of my columns, so I tried using the INSERT INTO table name (columns) VALUES (values) method and it's not working.

Table creation:

```
snprintf(sql_query,sizeof(sql_query), "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,%s TEXT NOT NULL, %s TEXT NOT NULL, %s TEXT NOT NULL,%s REAL NOT NULL, %s REAL NOT NULL, %s REAL NOT NULL);",tbl_id1,tbl_col1,tbl_col2,tbl_col3,tbl_col4,tbl_col5,tbl_col6,tbl_col7);
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql_query, callback, 0, NULL);
```

Insert:

```
sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)  VALUES ('%d/%d/%d','%d:%d:%d','4','%d','%d','7');",tbl_id1,tbl_col2,tbl_col3,tbl_col4,tbl_col5,tbl_col6,tbl_col7,year,month,day,hour,min,sec,peak,real);
int ic = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, NULL);
```

As I said, it works fine if I were to do it without specifying the columns I want to insert the data into.

Edit: [Names of my variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCoAy.png)

```
#define db_name     "db_test.db"
#define tbl_id1     "Meter1"
#define tbl_id2     "Meter2"
#define tbl_id3     "Meter3"
#define tbl_col1    "Run[#]"
#define tbl_col2    "Date[YY-MM-DD]"
#define tbl_col3    "Time[HH:MM:SS]"
#define tbl_col4    "Accept[True/False]"
#define tbl_col5    "F_Peak[N/cm]"
#define tbl_col6    "m_Peak[g]"
#define tbl_col7    "Cycle[s]"
```

Comment: Instead of posting tbl_id1,tbl_col2,tbl_col3 .... post the actual values so that we can see what are those values are.

Comment: `sprintf` is a very dangerous way to compose queries because it cannot handle proper [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com). Be very careful when constructing queries and use *prepared statements with placeholder values* whenever possible.

Comment: Please narrow down to either an SQLite problem or a C problem. To do so, try to insert as desired via SQLite commandline tool, using some sample data. If that fails, it is a SQLite problem. If it works it is a problem to do the same from C.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I have updated the post to show the values. And, as I mentioned before, the values I'm writing to the database are of the correct type, because I can pass them  without a problem when I don't specify the columns I want to insert data to.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've done as you said, and this statement using the command line works fine, so I guess this is a C problem.

Comment: So what happens if you use exactly the working string you tested in commandline, without any variable replacements?

Comment: @Yunnosch still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the ***column names***. With given values, sqlite3_exec returns SQLITE_ERROR (1) instead of SQLITE_OK (0).

Use column names without brackets (and everything within them) in INSERT query. For your example use following column names:

```
#define tbl_col1_clear    "Run"
#define tbl_col2_clear    "Date"
#define tbl_col3_clear    "Time"
#define tbl_col4_clear    "Accept"
#define tbl_col5_clear    "F_Peak"
#define tbl_col6_clear    "m_Peak"
#define tbl_col7_clear    "Cycle"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the issue.